# Take snapshot of the <div> using js/jquery/java/active x or anything else?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, activex

Basically, the task is simple, but I'm stuck on implementation. I need to take snapshot of the part of the page <div> using any tool(s) available (as long as it doesn't require any special installations and no flash (sorry adobe)).

Goal: Take snapshots of the <div> so that we can display it as a thumbnail/link of that subpage (any kind of image). <div> is sometimes may be flexible and always on the center of the page (so x&y window coordinates won't work), so it would be great if it's based on id or class of the <div>

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the [HTML to canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) JavaScript library.

The only issue you are going to have is that it will show you the `div` as it is rendered by the HTMLToCanvas rendering engine, not as it is rendered by, say Firefox 3.6.3 with the Digg plugin installed on a Mac OS X 10.6.7.

Comment: do you have any code references. actually am stuck on code implementation. how we use that on div.